# How to add special Character to a string in c#

Tags: c#, string, replace, special-characters

Good Morning all together,

I want to put some strings to getter and update entries in my wordpress database directly. For that I try to replace string like follows.

```cs
string test2 = @"halolg ' jijasf \";
string test3 = test2.Replace("'", @"\'");
```

Independently from what I do always get the character `"\"` twice in my string. Please look into the following example out of the debugger.

[image: Feedback from the debugger]

Comment: It's not actually there twice. There is only one backslash, but it is shown as an escaped backslash in Visual Studio because that is how it would be coded if you were using a normal string literal.

Comment: As Klitos said, that is just a debugger output, but if you output the string you can see it works how you want it to, see this fiddle for example https://dotnetfiddle.net/sS3GRM